# Verilog for loop - genvar vs int

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When creating logic using a for loop, Verilog requires the loop index to be declared. I've seen examples where it's done with either "int" or "genvar" keywords.
For example:

```
// Using genvar:
for (genvar x = 0 ; x < some_value ; x++) begin
// do something with reference to x
end 

// Using int:
for (int x = 0 ; x < some_value ; x++) begin
// do something with reference to x
end
```

When should I choose one over the other ?

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat historical. Prior to SystemVerilog, you had to declare the loop index separately, and prior to Verilog-2001, you had to enclose a generate-for loop with the keywords `generate/endgenerate`

```
module top;
  generate 
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i<4 ; i = i + 1) begin
       integer j;
       reg [i+1:0] value;
       initial for(j=0; j<4; j = j + 1) $display("i:%0d j:%0d value:%b",i,j, value);
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

This was to indicate that `i` was not an index variable, but was part of an elaboration unrolling construct. Verilog-2001 got rid of the need for the extra keywords because it could determine that the outer for-loop was a not procedural loop, and the inner for-loop was procedural.

SystemVerilog added the ability to declare the loop iteration index variable inside the for-loop, but it still requires you to use the `genvar` index declaration to inidicate that it is not really a variable.

```
module top;
    for (genvar i=0; i<4 ; i++) begin
           reg [i+1:0] value;
           initial for(int j=0; j<4; j++) $display("i:%0d j:%0d value:%b",i,j, value);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `genvar` only when the `for` loop is part of a `generate` construct.  A `for` loop need not be part of a `generate` construct.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27. *Generate constructs*.

Here is example code which illustrates 2 scenarios:

```
module tb;

wire [3:0] a, b;
reg  [3:0] c;

// Must use genvar for this generate construct
genvar i;
for (i=0; i<4; i++) begin
    assign a[i] = i;
end

// Must not use genvar since this is not a generate construct
int j;
always @* begin
    for (j=0; j<4; j++) begin
        c[j] = b[j];
    end
end

endmodule
```

The `generate/endgenerate` keywords are optional.

Comment: What if I want the logic to be generated inside an "always_ff" block ?
always_ff @ ( posedge clock ) begin for ("genvar/int ?" i=0;i<8,i++) begin y[i+1]<=x[i]. Should I declare i as an "int" or as a "genvar" ?